VBA Set Variable Equal to Column based on name in Row
Looking to see if I can search Row 2 for the title 'Country' and then use that whole column value later to select the row, copy it and paste it to a new sheet.
So Far I have the following, but I can't seem to get this to work.
Sub Extract_Country()

Dim CountryInput As Variant
Dim CountryCol As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim CopyRange As Range
Dim test As Single

CountryInput = Range("CountryInput")

startrow = 1
endrow = 2000
startcol = 1
number_of_columns = 200

'Take Away Merge
Rows("1:1").Select
With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With


Set CountryCol = Range("2:2").Find("Country")


'Copy Rows that Equal CountryInput
For i = 1 To endrow
    test = Cells(i, CountryCol)  'look in every row
    compare = StrComp(test, CountryInput, vbTextCompare)  'compare to the look up value
    
    If compare = 0 Then
        CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, ActiveRow)
    End If
    
Next i


'Create New Sheet
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet.Name = CountryInput & "1"

Any help much appreciated.
I keep tweaking but basically can't select the correct column as something is off with my reference.

Maybe test = Cells(i, CountryCol.Column), but why do you have Dim test As Single? That'll blow up when you hit row 2.

Looking to copy rows that meet the criteria in the 'country' column, i.e. anything in the country column named 'US', then copy the whole row.

And I thought single was just defining the precision of the input, not limiting it to a single test ?

You can use Autofilter to achieve what you want as shown HERE


Your code is close to finish. But you need to fix some syntax errors.

Option Explicit
Sub Extract_Country()
    Dim CountryInput As String
    Dim CountryCol As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range, ShtName As String
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, i As Long, desSht As Worksheet
    Const HEADER_ROW = 2
    Const END_ROW = 2000
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
    CountryInput = oSht.Range("CountryInput")
    'Take Away Merge
    With oSht.Rows(1)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    Set CountryCol = oSht.Rows(HEADER_ROW).Find("Country", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not CountryCol Is Nothing Then
        'Copy Rows that Equal CountryInput
        Dim c As Range, compare As Long
        For i = HEADER_ROW + 1 To END_ROW
            Set c = oSht.Cells(i, CountryCol.Column)  'look in every row
            compare = StrComp(CountryInput, c.Value, vbTextCompare)  'compare to the look up value
            If compare = 0 Then
                If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set CopyRange = c
                Else
                    Set CopyRange = Application.Union(CopyRange, c)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            ShtName = CountryInput & "1"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set desSht = Sheets(ShtName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If desSht Is Nothing Then
                Set desSht = Sheets.Add
                desSht.Name = ShtName
            Else
                desSht.Cells.Clear
            End If
            CopyRange.EntireRow.Copy desSht.Range("A1")
        End If
    End If
End Sub




AutoFitler is a good option (@Siddharth Rout
posted a comment first)

Option Explicit
Sub Extract_Country()
    Dim CountryInput As String
    Dim CountryCol As Range
    Dim CopyRange As Range, ShtName As String
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, i As Long, desSht As Worksheet
    Const HEADER_ROW = 2
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed
    CountryInput = oSht.Range("CountryInput")
    'Take Away Merge
    With oSht.Rows(1)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    Set CountryCol = oSht.Rows(HEADER_ROW).Find("Country", LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
    With oSht.Range("A2").CurrentRegion ' modify as needed
        .AutoFilter Field:=CountryCol.Column, Criteria1:=CountryInput
        On Error Resume Next
        Set CopyRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If CopyRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            ShtName = CountryInput & "1"
            On Error Resume Next
            Set desSht = Sheets(ShtName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If desSht Is Nothing Then
                Set desSht = Sheets.Add
                desSht.Name = ShtName
            Else
                desSht.Cells.Clear
            End If
            CopyRange.Copy desSht.Range("A1")
            ' remover header if needed
            ' desht.Rows(1).Delete
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub


Thank you, this was amazing and did the trick (and very quickly!). A quick follow up, if I wanted to be able to update the Sheets from [oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")] to link to an input from a master sheet, I don't seem able to get the variable right when changing it. Do I make it a string to pass into the Sheets input with something like [Sheet1= Range("SheetInput").Value Thanks!

oSht = Sheets(Sheets("mastersheetname").Range("SheetInput").Value) It's better to qualify the Range with sheet object (update sheet name as needed) because your code works with multiple sheets.
